# Is it possible to add images to treeview nodes without using a ImageList?

Tags: winforms, treeview, c#-2.0

(Using WinForms and C#. -> .Net 2.0)

I am adding nodes to a TreeView based on data in a table. As well as the caption to appear on the node, that data also contains Bitmaps.

I would like to use the Bitmap from the table as the icon on the TreeViewNode, not one from a pre-existing ImageList. (Normally you designate a Key or an Index of an image in an image list to set the node's image.)

Is this possible or do I need to add the Bitmap from my data to the ImageList (at runtime) then use that ImageList to populate the image on the node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have two options. You can populate an `ImageList` from your data like you're suggesting, or you can draw the image onto the control yourself (with the Paint event).

Comment: Yeh - that's what I've done. Seems a little overkill but works fine.